# Mysterious error caused by reference to invalid associated type in protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

An online Swift 5.1 compiler compiles the following code and reports errors. The most important one is stated as follows:

```
main.swift:18:23: error: reference to invalid associated type 'Other' of type 'Sparrow'
func sing(with f: Other) {
                  ^
```

Another thread on Stackoverflow brought up the same issue with a more complicated case. ([Reference to invalid associated type 'Iterator' of type 'DecodedArray<T>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965533/reference-to-invalid-associated-type-iterator-of-type-decodedarrayt)). There have been no answers to that thread yet.

The code for my case and a full list of compiler-reported errors is shown below:

```
    protocol Flier {
    associatedtype Other

    func flockTogether(with f:Other)
    func sing(with f:Other)
}

struct Sparrow : Flier {
    let name: String

    init (_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func flockTogether(with f: Other) {
        print("Birds, \(name), and \(f.name), of a feather flock together.")
    }
    func sing(with f: Other) {
        sing()
        f.sing()
    }
    func sing () {
        print("Sparrow sings \"chirp, chirp\"!")
    }
}

struct Parrot {
    let name: String

    init (_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func sing () {
        print("Parrot sings \"chuck, chuck\"!")
    }
}
struct Canary: Flier {
    let name: String
        
    init (_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    func flockTogether(with f: Other) {}
    func sing(with f: Other) {}

    func sing () {
        print("Canary sings \"tweet, tweet\"!")
    }
}
let sparrow = Sparrow("sparrow")
let parrot = Parrot("parrot")
let canary = Canary("canary")
sparrow.flockTogether(with: parrot)
sparrow.sing(with: parrot)
sparrow.flockTogether(with: canary)
sparrow.sing(with: canary)
```

The errors reported by the compiler:

```
main.swift:18:23: error: reference to invalid associated type 'Other' of type 'Sparrow'
    func sing(with f: Other) {
                      ^
main.swift:8:8: error: type 'Sparrow' does not conform to protocol 'Flier'
struct Sparrow : Flier {
       ^
main.swift:2:20: note: protocol requires nested type 'Other'; do you want to add it?
    associatedtype Other
                   ^
main.swift:38:8: error: type 'Canary' does not conform to protocol 'Flier'
struct Canary: Flier {
       ^
main.swift:2:20: note: protocol requires nested type 'Other'; do you want to add it?
    associatedtype Other
                   ^
compiler exit status 1
```

Please help me find out what has gone wrong in the above code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Shouldn't Parrot conform to Flier protocol? Shouldn't Flier protocol require a name property? Shouldn't Flier require a generic method (Flier) called sing ? Why would you need an associatedtype? try `protocol Flier {`
    `var name: String { get }`
    `func flockTogether<Other: Flier>(with f: Other)`
    `func sing<Other: Flier>(with f: Other)`
    `func sing()`
`}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with this code.

1. `Sparrow` and `Canary` are declared to conform to `Flier` yet doesn't say what their respective `Other` type is.
2. You are trying to pass both a `parrot` and a `canary` to `sparrow.flockTogether(with:)` and `sparrow.sing(with:)`, but those methods only accept one type of object - `Sparrow.Other`. This, and the above point, suggest that you might be misunderstanding what associated types are. I suggest you [read about them](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID189).
3. You are trying to access things that doesn't necessarily exist, such as `f.name` and `f.sing()`. Recall that `f` is an `Other`, which is not constrained to any type, so it can be ***anything***. And "anything" won't always have a `name` for you to access.

I suggest the following to make the callers work:

1. Remove the associated type and use generic methods instead. Associated types are inappropriate if the caller gets to decide whether to pass in a `Parrot` or `Canary`.
2. Add `name` and `sing()` to `Flier` so that the compiler knows that anything conforming to `Flier` has those members. If we then constrain `Other` (the generic parameter of the aforementioned generic methods) to `Flier`, then we can access `sing()` and `name` without any problems.
3. Conform `Parrot` to `Flier` as well

The fixed code now looks like:

```
protocol Flier {
    var name: String { get }
    func flockTogether<Other: Flier>(with f:Other)
    func sing<Other: Flier>(with f:Other)
    func sing()
}

struct Sparrow : Flier {
    let name: String

    init (_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func flockTogether<Other: Flier>(with f:Other) {
        print("Birds, \(name), and \(f.name), of a feather flock together.")
    }
    func sing<Other: Flier>(with f:Other) {
        sing()
        f.sing()
    }
    func sing () {
        print("Sparrow sings \"chirp, chirp\"!")
    }
}

struct Parrot : Flier{
    func flockTogether<Other>(with f: Other) where Other : Flier { }
    
    func sing<Other>(with f: Other) where Other : Flier { }
    
    let name: String

    init (_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func sing () {
        print("Parrot sings \"chuck, chuck\"!")
    }
}
struct Canary: Flier {
    let name: String

    init (_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    func flockTogether<Other: Flier>(with f:Other) {}
    func sing<Other: Flier>(with f:Other) {}

    func sing () {
        print("Canary sings \"tweet, tweet\"!")
    }
}
```